# Loading every inner folder inside a directory and saving

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have around 40 folders with 50 images inside each folder that i am adding noise to them. What i am doing is rewritting the path for every time i need to add noises to the 50 images and also write the path where the folder will be saved.

For instance:

```
loadimage_with_noise('C:/Users/Images/folder 1/')
```

This will load every image inside folder 1, but i have folders up to 40, so i have to keep rewritting all the paths all the way to folder 40th

the code that does it:

```
def loadimage_with_noise(path):
    filepath_list = listdir(path)
    for filepath in filepath_list:
        img = Image.open(path + filepath)
        img = img.resize((81, 150))
        img = np.asarray(img)
        noise_image = generate_noisy_image(img, 0.10)
        noise_image = Image.fromarray(noise_image)
        noise_image = noise_image.convert("L")
        folder_index = 'folder 2/'
        noise_image.save('C:/Users/Images/Noise/'+folder_index +filepath, 'JPEG')
```

function that adds the noise

```
def generate_noisy_image(x, variance):
    noise = np.random.normal(0, variance, (150, 81))
    return x + noise
```

What i want to do is automate this task, instead of passing as parameter a new path for every folder inside my folder of images, i'd like to simply: for every folder, load every image inside and save them in a new folder (the noise is already being added), for every folder inside my Images folder

So for each 40 folders with 50 images, i will have new 40 folders with 50 images in a different directory

Comment: You already know of the function `listdir`. Why not use that one to iterate all the folder in `C:/Users/Images/`?

Comment: I dont know how to save them as it loops through

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand what you need to save. So in the folder `Images` you have x number of folders with the name `folder {number}`, which contains several images. And you want to save the noisy images where?

Comment: Im adding noise to the images as they are being read, and saving the images now with noise, there really is no criteria for where, as long as its not the same folder, i just want to: load, add noise, save

Comment: Use a global variable, use an extra argument in your function. Idk what you have problems with.

Comment: You're right, im already doing that, the problem was that i was setting specific paths, i dont have to

Comment: So your program works now like intended?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use os.walk

```py
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/Users/Images/"):
   for name in files:
      image_path = os.path.join(root, name)
      process_your_image(image_path)
```

Comment: How do you propose i save the images?

Comment: Where do you want to save it ? The simpliest case is just to set a path to another folder  and save the image there

Comment: anywhere really, but inside a different folders

Comment: make a folder called Images2
    path = C:/Users/Images2/
    noise_image.save(path + name)

Comment: Ill have to change the path directory 40 times: in short what i am trying to do is load 40 folder images and for each folder load, add noise and save inside a different folder. So, ill have new 40 folders of 50 images, but now with noise